# anim file doesn't exist:

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I need support for this problem---anim file doesn't exist: E:\Blender Animations\UNIVERSALAthmosphere1\x\0001-0600.avi
anim file doesn't exist: E:\Blender Animations\UNIVERSALSun\0001-0325.avi

this problem apper when i trie to do "Render"

and my project look like this:

[image]

Comment: It looks like Blender is trying to access files that are not there? Have you tried to look in these folders to see where the files are?

Comment: the files are on folder,i seing there, but i dont know why dont read or recognizer, i will tried to installed all again

Comment: how are you calling these files in your scene?

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you could pack the external files in your .blend file (file > external data > pack all into .blend), upload the .blend on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) or any other site and share the link here so that we can search the issue oursleves.